# How do I dynamically assign a port in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want `http://example.com/test/4000`(or some other number) to proxy_pass to `http://localhost:4000/test`.

Is this possible, and how do I do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you should first think of url structure. Do you want it `/test/4000/path/to/file` or `/test/path/to/file/4000`. From my point of view, it's better to set port as first part of path (`/4000/test/..`) or even better as subdomain (`http://4000.example.com/test`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that I would like the port to come first as well. Could you post an example of how to do this? I have tried a couple different ways without success.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # default port for proxy
    set $port 80;

    # redirect /4000 --> /4000/ just to be sure
    # that next rewrite works properly
    rewrite ^(/\d+)$ $1/ redirect;

    # rewrite /4000/path/to/file to /path/to/file
    # and store port number to variable
    rewrite ^/(?<port>\d+)(.+)$ $2;

    location / {
        # proxy request to localhost:$port
        proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
    }
}
```

It proxies request to `/PORT_NUMBER/path/to/file` to `localhost:PORT_NUMBER/path/to/file`. If url doesn't start with port number it falls back to 80 so request to `/path/to/file` will be proxied to `localhost:80/path/to/file`.

There is no check if port number is valid so it's not recommended to use it for production. But using variable port number in production is really bad idea anyway.